# How to select h4 tag here?

Tags: jquery

This is the code:

```
<div id="question" style="float: right">
    <a id="score" href="#">
        <img id="@Model.QuestionId" src="~/Content/1369264038_arrow_sans_up.png" /></a>
    <h4 id="number" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 7px; color: #808080;">
        @Model.Score
    </h4>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="~/Content/1369263927_arrow_sans_down.png" /></a>
</div>
```

I want to know how to select the `<h4>` tag here in JQuery?
Note that I am writing function for `<a id="score">`:

```
$("#score").live("click",function(){
        var entityId = $(this).children("img").attr("id");
        $.getJSON('/Question/Score', { score: 1, entityTypeId: 1, id: entityId }, function (data) {
            //here I want to change h4 tag content
        });
    })
```

Edit:
I may have some of these h4 tags but I want to select the one after this `<a id="score">`.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated.

Comment: Just use `$("#number")`, `number` is the id for your `<h4>` tag.

Answer (score 4):

Well it has its own id, so:

```
$('#number")
```

In case you have more `h4` around, consider:

```
$('#question h4')
```

Comment: In case there are more `h4` around there, it still makes more sense to use the ID as selector.

Comment: @KilianStinson when I answered the goal was not clear yet, I thought it had more styling purposes and the OP wanted to catch them all ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
$("h4")
OR
$("div > h4")
OR
$("div h4")
OR
$("#question div")
OR
$("#question > div")
OR
$("#number")
```

Comment: @JurijsNesterovs that's true, but the context of the question isn't averse to that.

Comment: Each of these choices has advantages. Some are more specific than others. The choice depends upon the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Since it has an ID (which should be unique), you don't need to make it relative to the `score` element, as you're asking in the question; you can just select it directly: `$("#number")`.

But since you've specified that you want it relative to `score`, you can use jQuery's [`.sibling()` method](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to find it as a sibling of `score`:

```
$score = $('#score');
$h4 = $score.siblings('h4');
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var h4 = $('h4#number');
```

Comment: There's no reason for the `h4` in front of the ID.

Comment: Yeah! I know, but if in other page there is another id 'number' with other tag I not want get that! ;)

Sorry for my english!